# Use mock or create real instance with workaround while testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have defined the class `MyClass` in the file `main.py` as follows:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    
        self.d = None
        self.e = None
        self.f = None
    
    def method_1(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    
    def method_2(self):
        return self.d + 4
    
    def method_3(self):
        return self.e + 10
    
    def run(self):
        self.d = self.method_1()
        self.e = self.method_2()
        self.f = self.method_3()
        # a lot more stuff here that takes time
```

In the file `test_file.py` I have written the following test methods:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
    
from main import MyClass
    
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method_2_v1(self):
        # This test creates a real instance, but the attribute d is created
        # manually in the test, while in the production code is created
        # by the method run()
        instance = MyClass()
        instance.d = instance.method_1()
        instance.e = instance.method_2()
        assert instance.e == 7
    
    def test_method_2_v2(self):
        # As in the version 1 this test creates a real instance and the attribute
        # d is created manually in the test, but  This case does not run method_1
        # and gives an explicit value to attribute d
        instance = MyClass()
        instance.d = 3
        instance.e = instance.method_2()
        assert instance.e == 7
    
    @patch('main.MyClass', spec=True)
    def test_method_2_v3(self, my_class_mock):
        # This test uses a mock and verify the correctness of method_2()
        # directly on the mock object 
        mock_instance = my_class_mock()
        mock_instance.configure_mock(d=3)
        assert MyClass.method_2(mock_instance) == 7
```

The differences between the three test methods are explained by the code and comments inside the code.

Which one is the best practice and why?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: I can see that test_method_2_v1() is the worst, since it makes the test depend on method_1(), making the test more fragile.

Answer (score 0):

### Main difference between the 3 methods

I think that the main difference between the 3 test methods is:

- `test_method_2_v1()` invokes `method_1()` of `MyClass`
- `test_method_2_v2()` and `test_method_2_v3()` don't invoke `method_1()` of `MyClass`

This means that `test_method_2_v1()` executes an indirect test of `method_1()` while the other 2 test methods execute only a test of `method_2()`.

### Comparison between  *test_method_2_v2()* and *test_method_2_v3()*

Between `test_method_2_v2()` and `test_method_2_v3()` I think that the best is  `test_method_2_v3()` because the use of a mock object, when it is possible, is in general preferable because it helps to create unit tests (a mock object is used to simulate the behaviour of an object in a precise `test case` and not an whole object).

A unit test is a test which verifies a specific functionality. In this case `test_method_2_v3()` verifies that `method_2()` returns the value of the attribute `d` increase of `4`.

In my opinion `test_method_2_v2()` does too many things so it's not a good unit test.

### How *test_method_2_v2()* becomes a unit-test

I think is better to modify `test_method_2_v2()` and a possible code for it is the following:

```
def test_method_2_v2(self):
  instance = MyClass()
  instance.d = 3
  # check that method_2 return 'd' increases of 4
  assert instance.method_2() == 7
```

Previous code becomes similar to `test_method_2_v3()` without using of mock object. Now `test_method_2_v2()` only verifies the correctness of `method_2()` (as a test unit must do).

Comment: Very clear, thanks for the answer. I agree that in test_method_2_v2 the inputs of the method are being created manually, and that is not good practice, since the production code is not doing it in the same way. However, there is this general practice of trying to avoid mocks if possible, and here it is possible. In addition, I believe test_method_2_v2 is a bit more readable.

Comment: @Arman I have understood your point of you; I have made some modifications to my answer. If you want check them out.